# Please suggest a user-mode filesystem filter framework

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, ntfs

I need a user-mode filesystem filter (not virtual filesystem). One of such frameworks is http://eldos.com/cbflt/, but it has some bugs and I need an alternative.
Can you please suggest similar frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CallbackFilter is the only *filter* driver solution available. You mention dokan and fuse, but they are not filters, they are file system drivers (like Callback File System). This is a very different thing.

If you have problems with CallbackFilter, please report them to tech.support and we will address the issues ASAP.

Comment: Sad but true :) There is no other similar products.

Comment: You are welcome to contact tech.support with issues. Yes, CallbackFilter has things to be improved, and we are working on them all the time, so your feedback will help a lot. And discounts are provided as well.

Comment: Last time I reported a problem with CallbackFilter (it bluescreened XP) the sales guy was just damn rude. Really unprofessional, but I haven't been able to find anything else...

Comment: @Cocowalla A appologize for possible misunderstanding: I believe part of this is due to shortcomings of written language and language barriers. To say for sure, I'd like to see the communication - we have track of all communications and it would be nice to find it. Unfortunately I can't see anything in HelpDesk or in the forum (or in Live Chat transcripts) that can be identified by your local nick.

Comment: Easevault File System Filter Driver SDK (http://www.easevault.com) is a similar product, so CallbackFilter is no longer the only option

Comment: @Cocowalla if you want my comments on this, please contact me privately.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a user-mode FS filter.

You could write a [minifilter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540402.aspx) that delegates the computing (of the I/O operation verdict) to a user mode component [through a port](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541931%28VS.85%29.aspx) and reports back the result.
You can check out */src/filesystem/miniFilter/scanner* sample in the [WinDDK](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/wdk/).

Comment: Check this out: https://eldos.com/cbflt/
I need similar technologies.

Comment: @skevar7: clyfe is right. what you link to is a plain trickery using windows hooks. and it can be sometimes bypassed. google for "windows hooks" for more.

Comment: hooks????? what hooks have to do with this framework?

Comment: @skevar the software in your link uses a filter driver like i described, check technical specifications under "driver" section

Comment: @clyfe you should read question more carefully. This framework does exactly what I need. I just need similar frameworks to choose the best.

Comment: +1, this answer is accurate.  Use Google for shopping.

Comment: Why don't you just don't write anything, if you don't have an answer?

Comment: You're attitude towards people trying to help is questionable. I get the feeling you are trying to advertise that worthless software $$$. What do you gain by using that? It installs a driver anyway, there is nothing "user-mode" in it!

Comment: Yeah I have to agree with the previous posters. Your attidude stinks! Also, everytime I see someone write "plz" I have to throw up. -1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to happen, you are going to have to write a minifilter driver.

Any solution attempting to do this is going to fail in a very bad way.

Many callbacks in the minifilter frameowrk can be called at dispatch level and cannot be delegated to userland.  Not to mention netowrk share access would be all messed up. Marshalling access tokens from kernel->user on the write path would be a bluescreen factory.

Comment: You are wrong too, there are such tools. FUSE, Dokan, etc. I just need a tool which suits my needs.

Comment: Well, then.  See: http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=user+mode+file+system+filter.  I can't see anything, so it likely does not exist.  Get over it.